# How to identify in googlemaps with below data

Tags: google-maps, india

How to draw polygon in google maps with below point data?It should be plot in India Andhrapadesh

```
startpoint endpoint     startpoin xpos , Ypos   endpoint xpos,ypos
_0  _2          713.955,    1068.269    712.619 ,1063.695

_2  8           712.619 ,1063.695   584.191,996.972

8   22          584.191 ,996.972    319.606 ,1074.288
22  10          319.606 ,1074.288   154.1318,1033.283
10  11         154.1318,1033.283    223.4312,948.496

11  12         223.4312,948.496     303.9466,783.483
12  14         303.9466 ,783.483    357.2076,643.81

14  16         357.2076 ,643.81         135.8306,445.3878
16  17      135.8306,445.3878            50,304.1624
17  _23      50.304.1624           99.9322, 288.651
_23 _24 99.9322,288.651              165.7518   ,268.2042
_24 _25 165.7518,268.2042          304.2002,225.1952
_25 25  304.2002,225.1952          288.691, 175.27
```

Comment: It isn't at all obvious how this data should be presented. Can you provide some more detail on where the data came from, and how you think it should be plotted?

Answer (score 1):

The data is in some kind of projected CRS, that has coordinates in metres.

You have to find out which CRS is used. For most surveying data, a high number constant has to be added to the X and Y coordinates to get the full CRS coordinates.

With that, you can reproject the data to WGS84 to use them in Google Earth.

GDAL `cs2cs` is an easy tool to mass reproject point coordinates.

For India, you can use this conversion tool: https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/gis/indian-grid/conversion.htm

Comment: Data is collected under Zone IIIa, this is CRS. We are not clear how to reproject the data to WGS84, Could you please guide us step by step?

Comment: With only three digits before the decimal point it is impossible to do any reprojection.